# Link Title in list to value in URL column

Tags: list, url

I have a default custom list with 3 values: 
- Title 
- Description
- URL

What I'm trying to do is fill the Title with a name, fill the description with text
and automatically create a page with the title: eg. mysharepoint.com/names/'title I set when I add an item'

Well everything works with an event receiver except one thing. The value in title links to a default display form and my value in the URL column links to the site I wanted to link the title column to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose this solution:

1. Create calculated column.
2. Insert following formula -
   `="<a href='"&UrlFieldName&"'>"&Title&"</a>"`
3. Set "data type returned from this formula is" to integer.

As a result on list view you will see the title with link to your url.

UPD: It seems that URL field is not valid for calculated column, as workaround you can copy url value in a receiver into another text field, which is not shown on the view.

**UPD 2**: See the [comment](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/58954/link-title-in-list-to-value-in-url-column/58978?noredirect=1#comment295372_58978) from @Tally:

> For anyone else wishing to use this as a solution, Microsoft no longer
>   allow HTML in calculcated columns, so this won't work any more.

Comment: What do you mean by "you can copy url value in a receiver into the another text field"?

Comment: For anyone else wishing to use this as a solution, Microsoft no longer allow HTML in calculcated columns, so this won't work any more.

Answer (score 0):

Great solution, but your formula doesn't work for me. 
Correct formula is: =CONCATENATE(""&[Title]&"")

I've tried it a lot of times, with various of formulas from this or other sites, but it takes me only one long string with URL + Title. 
But with this correct formula it works!

No coding, no scripts :)
I use SharePoint 2013 Online

Thank you, Kai, great solution!

Comment: Hi David, I've tried out your formula but it only returns the Title value in my calculated column.  I also found that I was not able to incorportate a url column in my formula.

Comment: Try this: =CONCATENATE("<a href=' "&[URLlink]&" '>"&[Title]&"</a>")

Comment: Hi David, thanks for taking the trouble to reply.  Microsoft no longer allow html in calculated columns (there's a very popular post on this in SPSE).  For my own particular requirements, I've since found a way around it (answer by Michael Han): https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/277400/paste-a-url-together-with-title-display-text-in-quick-edit-mode